# Autodesk Maya - Towers of Hanoi

Tags: python, recursion, maya, towers-of-hanoi, autodesk

Hi I think this may be the wrong place to be asking but here goes! I was wondering if anyone here is good at scripting in maya? I finally understand the recursive code for the Towers of Hanoi in Python and I am now trying to implement it in maya. Does anyone know how to go about using the recursive code to move discs that I have created in Autodesk Maya?

I have created the required geometry and the number of discs can be changed by the user. I now want to write script that will solve the problem with the correct moves (and yes in the end i would like to animate the solution, although I think the animation should be easy once Ive figured out how to solve the puzzle in maya)

I am unsure where to start adding in the relevant xform commands.

Kind regards

Comment: Are you trying to animate the disks, or just position them as your script solves the problem? Do you have the geometry already or do you need to build it? Putting boundaries around your specific problem to help us answer just the parts your stuck on will help narrow down the solution. Otherwise this question will likely be closed as being "too broad"

Comment: One doesnt need recursive algorhitm, but can use simple logic described @ wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution

Comment: @mhlester hi I have already created the geometry - i'll edit the question to try and make it more specific! thanks for the tips I'm new to SO :)

Comment: And Luke I hade a look at doing it iteratively but i can't seem to find a way to make that work? if you could explain i'd be really grateful :)